# usb-c performance issue

Tags: usb, keyboard, hdmi, usb-c

**tl;dr: usb-c port's performance has gone down; looking for cause and solution**

on the usb-c port of my dell xps 13 (kaby lake), I'm using a dongle that has an hdmi and a usb-a (and unused usb-c) port. The hdmi-port is used for an external monitor, and the usb-a connects to a hub that has some periferals (mice, wireless keyboard). This setup has always worked well in the past.

The problem I now have is the following. Recently, the external wireless keyboard appeared to have an issue, with many key presses not being registered, or registered after a large lag. When using the laptop's own keyboard, there is no problem, and more importantly, when using the wireless receiver in one of the laptop's usb-a ports, there is also no problem. It seems to be a throughput problem on the part of the usb-c port or the dongle I've attached. As it was not a problem before, I suspect the problem is caused by an update (ubuntu 17.10?).

My questions:

1) is this a known issue?

2) is there a solution? By plugging the receiver into its own usb-a port, I found a workaround, but there seems to be a deeper issue here.

I can do more diagnoses if necessary.

Many thanks

Comment: Hmmmm... nobody? Is there any more information I could give?